# sqlite php login not running

Tags: php, sqlite, authentication

I can't seem to find an error with my code even when I cross check it with other questions on stackoverflow. Can someone else see some stupid mistake I'm making? It usually is a stupid mistake.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$user = $_REQUEST['myusername'] ; 
$pass = $_REQUEST['mypassword'] ;
$salt = "TheSaltGoesHere";
$password = md5($salt.$pass);

$db = new PDO("sqlite:/resources/database.db");
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clients WHERE user = '$user' AND pass = '$password'");
if ($result->fetchColumn() > 0) {
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
 echo "It worked";
};

if(!$_SESSION['loggedin']){
echo "It failed";
exit;
};



?>
```

I'm getting a plain 500 error. But my syntax is correct.

Comment: You're using PDO, but not using prepared queries.  What you are doing is extremely insecure, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared queries to avoid SQL injection attacks entirely.  In addition, don't use MD5 for password hashes.  There are better algorithms available, such as sha1. Also, it's hard to help you since you didn't post the actual error you're getting.  Go check your error log for the details of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues, so I have posted a minor re-write. This uses prepared statements. As for MD5, well I guess that depends on your user base, well done for using a salt anyway. I put in a debug switch so you can see some info if it does not work with your code straight away.

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_REQUEST['myusername'] ; 
$pass = $_REQUEST['mypassword'] ;
$salt = "ysgf8o3w74gf";
$password = md5($salt.$pass);
$debug = true;

try {
  $db = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');
  if($debug) $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  if($debug) echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  die();
}

if($debug) $db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (user TEXT, pass TEXT);');

$statement = $db->prepare('
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clients WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass
');
$statement->bindValue(':user',  $user );
$statement->bindValue(':pass',  $pass );
$statement->execute();

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;

if ($statement->fetchColumn() > 0) {
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
 echo "It worked";
};

if(!$_SESSION['loggedin']){
echo "It failed";
exit;
};

?>
```